# File isn't sent after successful upload - Jmeter

Tags: file-upload, automation, jmeter, upload, automated-tests

I'm with the following problem:
I'm using the tool Jmeter for automated testing.

One of the services is to send a file, using the method PUT in the URL.
I correctly place the call. The status HTTP is 200!
However, when i verify the next endpoint, a GET this URL with the file, the image is not in it.

I've done the same test in Postman. It sent the file successfully!!

Why this??
Could anyone help?

**Follow below the test:**

```
PUT https://s3.amazonaws.com/cl-dev-identity-xxxxx....
```

**In Sampler HTTP Requests > Files Upload:**

```
    File Path: C:\Users\me\testing.png;
```

```
    Parameter name: I added a any parameter name, in this case, "upload";
```

```
    MIME Type: image/png
```

**Selected**

> Use KeepAlive

> Use multipart/form-data

I await you!!!
Thank you!

Comment: Please check the upload path "C:\\Users\me\testing.png";..it should be something like C:\Users\xxx...if it is a typo..then please share if there are any error logs

Comment: Hi @sunny_teo . I wrote wrong! I adjusted the upload path.

There are no errors... =//. 

Only different return is as follows, but in own request body:
<actual file content, not shown here>

Comment: Not working for me too. The file is not getting captured. The postman is successful. Any luck?

Answer (score 1):

If request works in Postman but doesn't work in JMeter - you're not sending the same request, you're sending different requests.

It is impossible to tell what's wrong without seeing your full Postman and JMeter requests configurations so I can give you only generic piece of advice: just record the request from Postman using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

1. Start HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
2. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/proxy/)

   [image]
3. Copy the file you're going to upload to the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation. This step is essential, otherwise JMeter won't be able to properly capture the request. see [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details
4. Execute the request in Postman
5. JMeter will capture the request and generate the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

Comment: Weird, @Dmitri T ...
 this requires a root CA certificate.
I don't have it in my bin folder. Why?